# Собрать python из исходников?

Tags: python, c++, c, mingw, build

Хотел обновить python 3.8 до 3.8.18 с багфиксами. На офф-сайте только исходники, в [build-readme](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/PCbuild/readme.txt) предлагают установить VisualStudio. Хотелось бы обойтись одним mingw, или это невозможно? Опыта компиляции "C" нету.

Comment: https://devguide.python.org/getting-started/setup-building/

Comment: построенный в mingw не имел бы доступа к ряду API. Майкрософтский компилятор (оболочка не обязательна) - к сожалению, единственно средство сборки приложений использующих API WIndows напрямую.

Comment: Надо еще посмотреть, не предлагает ли новая студия уже собранный 3.8.18. python ставится как доп-компонент, судия его поддерживает.